# Intermittent issues on iis 7.5 site running wordpress, internal error 500

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, wordpress, intermittent

This happened to a wordpress site that was working previously, the server is running IIS 7.5 on Server 2k8 R2 (fully patched).

On the friendsofridingmountain.ca site, browsing through the pages will intermittently get you a internal server error 500 page. It doesn't seem to matter what link on the site you try and get to, they all have a chance of giving you the error 500

The flow that happens when you are about to get this issue, is the site will take approximately 30-45 seconds to load before leaving you with a blank screen. (I do have external error pages enabled and followed: [How to diagnose a 500 Internal Server Error on IIS 7.5 when nothing is written to the event log?](https://serverfault.com/questions/407954/how-to-diagnose-a-500-internal-server-error-on-iis-7-5-when-nothing-is-written-t) already (as there is no flags raised in event viewer on this issue). To no avail

I enabled failed request tracing on error 500 for this site below is the trace:

```
ModuleName: FastCgiModule 
Notification: 128 
HttpStatus:   500 
HttpReason    Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode     0 
ConfigExceptionInfo Notification
    EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

The full trace shows an execution time of 103750 ms, the trac75. -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName FastCgiModule 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 500 
HttpReason Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo 
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

I have the full trace if required.

*Edit PHP version is 5.4.9

Comment: What version of PHP? Are you running WinCache or any PHP extensions?

Comment: The website is running PHP 5.4.9, with a mysql server 5.6.14

The only extension I know running is PEAR, have a look at http://friendsofridingmountain.ca/infophp.php.

First I've heard of WinCache honestly, do you recommend it?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend Wincache. It's an opcode cache similar to Xcache or APC, usually helpful for performance. Any chance you can upgrade PHP? 5.4.9 is really old, the latest 5.4 is 5.4.38. They may have fixed a bug that is causing your problem.

Comment: I udpated to 5.6 and installed WinCache, my failed request tracing has reported that the last instance was 11:30 AM.

Case closed my friend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved, probelem was fixed by updating php 5.4.9 to 5.6 and installing wincache.